# Strange 404 server error (ListenAndServeTLS)

Tags: go, https, http-status-code-404

2 days ago I started to get these 404 errors:

> Chrome console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 ()

I can run this compiled code on any PC without getting problems except on the PC (Win10) I am developing with. **How can I find the problem source?** I am starting to get really confused and have tried dozens of variations with and without gorilla/mux and others.

This is a simple version of what I am using (I also tried with this of course)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloServer)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

The certificates are self signed and are imported as trusted root ca. and are also valid until 2029.

Comment: windows 10 sometimes has other services running on port 443. try changing the port to 8080 and access it via https protocol eg: https://localhost:8080/hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windows 10 sometimes has other services running on port 443. try changing the port to 8080 and access it via https protocol eg: **localhost:8080/hello**

Comment: Big thanks to you, @Krishna. I just saw that VMware had a service running on port 443. After closing that, it works. It is just strange to me, that I did not change the settings for VMware and it must have been running there before.